# WCF Data Annotations for arrays of objects (DataContract'ed)

Tags: c#, validation, wcf, data-annotations

I have some WCF service and I am using WCF Data Annotations (from devTrends) to validate.

```
[DataContract]
public class SomeClass {
   [DataMember]
   [Required] // annotation provided by WCF Data Annotations (DevTrends)
    public string SomeRequiredField {get; set;}

}
```

I have some endpoint: 
`/soSomeStuff (SomeClass s)`
Here, object `s` is properly validated.

However, in case of other endpoint:
`/soSomeStuffs (SomeClass s[])`
validation doesn't work.

How to force this framework to validate also array of elements?

Comment: Do you have any code you can include in your question?

Comment: @TimHutchison I attached.

Comment: Why don't you use `IsRequired` attribute of `DataMember` instead, like this:  `[DataMember(IsRequired = true)]`?

Comment: This one doesn't work for me, however DataAnnotations works well.